# How to extract a specific words/text from a cell into another cell

Tags: string, google-sheets, lambda, google-sheets-formula, textjoin

If in a cell there are few texts like, `Hi, How are you, Hello`.
I want to show in another cell if that cell contains either `Hi` and/or `Hello` and display the exact text on another cell.

[image]

I'm using Google Sheets.

I'm a beginner and searched a lot about my question but didn't find any.

Comment: The find() function is one, take care with upper & lower case though.

Comment: Why tag Excel 365? That is not Googlesheets, they are different.

Comment: Thank you, Formulas are the same though, I belive. Apologies. Could you please share the complete formula ?

Comment: Some functions are the same, others have arguments displaced while others don’t exist.

Comment: @SolarMike Thank you, I have removed the tags. Could you please share the complete formula here for the above problem as I'm not sure how to use Find() function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `search` if you don't care about case sensitivity:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",true,
 if(isnumber(search("hi",a2)),"hi",""), 
  if(isnumber(search("hello",a2)),"hello",""))
```

If case-sensative then:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",true,
 if(isnumber(find("hi",A2)),"hi",""), 
  if(isnumber(FIND("hello",A2)),"hello",""))
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please guide me on how to learn all these formulas, functions and there applicability just like you solved the above problem?

Comment: could you please help me out with the below problem as well ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74854182/fetch-details-from-multiple-spreadsheets

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=INDEX(BYROW(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT(A2:A5, ", "), "(?i)hello|hi")), 
 LAMBDA(x, TEXTJOIN(", ", 1, x))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Player0, could you please share the logic here as well or the link related to the above formula?

Comment: @RamanSingh sure logic is simple... we SPLIT each cell in A column by comma , and REGEXEXTRACT hello or hi no matter the case (?i) so it can he even hELLo. this will either result in extracted value or error that we hide with IFNA. next we row-wise (using BYROW) TEXTJOIN all split extracts and we done

Comment: Could you please help me out with the below problem as well?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74854182/fetch-details-from-multiple-spreadsheets