# Fetch details from multiple spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have 2 spreadsheets where below data is given.[image: Sheet1]

Step 1: Where a user and its "ID" are provided in columns 'A' and 'B' (could be multiple).

Step 2: The outputs (in column 'C') provided against the "ID" should be displayed in column 'D'
(If the output given in column 'C' contains "HI" and, or "Hello" then it should display in column 'D')

In Spreadsheet 2:
[image: Sheet 2]

Step 3: In spreadsheet 2, column 'A'("ID") should match with column 'B' of spreadsheet 1 and display the number of:
"HI" (In column 'C')
"Hello" (In column 'D')
"HI & Hello (Both)" (In column 'E')
Anything other than "HI and/or Hello" (In column 'F')

Step 4: The 'Relationship Advisor' mentioned in column 'G' of spreadsheet 2 should reflect in column 'E' of spreadsheet 1.

Comment: it would help if you could share a sample editable sheet with demo data and expected output (manually done) so that we can work it out easily.

Comment: Thank you rockinfreakshow. will add the sheet

Comment: @rockinfreakshow, here is the link to the sample sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TBtN2Q7bVFnfL6tbpfwMpzd2xKf5ovmqvzXPB_Q_Bgg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: can you provide some insight on the COUNT value results (1,2,5) provided in column F - values other than HI and Hello?!

Comment: It is the values of empty rows in Column D in SpreadSheet 1 (1st Image) (that is the output other than "HI" and "Hello"

Comment: @RamanSingh, I responded. Assuming this helps you, I'd be appreciative if you accepted. I only responded as you accepted my previous one. Please minimize your questions to a single issue, not "someone please do my work for me!". Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of what you're requesting is similar to [your previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74594294/11732320) and you should familiarize yourself with the [search function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094154?hl=en&ref_topic=3105625). The Search function will return a `true` value if the text appears anywhere in the string, and `false` when it does not. This can enable you to accomplish most of the rest of your request.

To illustrate with your first sheet and populating column `D` you could use this dynamic formula (put in cell `D2`)

```
=filter(if(ISNUMBER(search("hi",C2:C)),"hi",
        if(ISNUMBER(search("hello",C2:C)),"hello",""))
             ,C2:C<>"")
```

**What this does**

- The filter function ensures that we're making a formula for every cell from `c2:c` that has a value in it.
- The first line is an if statement searches if "hi" appears in column `c`. If a value appears, it returns `true` and returns `hi` as the true condition of the if statement.
- If the above if statement returns false, it repeats the search only for `hello` and in turn returns `hello` if found.
- If false, it returns `""`.
- The last line is connected to filtering.

If you wanted to return the exact case from column `c` you could use this:

```
=filter(if(ISNUMBER(search("hi",C2:C)), 
     mid(C2:C,search("hi",C2:C),2),
     if(ISNUMBER(search("hello",C2:C)),
        mid(C2:C,search("hello",C2:C),5),))
         ,C2:C<>"")
```

While this obviously doesn't address all of your to-do list, this concept should be able to get you close to resolving most of what you're doing.